# Change vertex color when plotting community object in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to run a community detection algorithm on a graph `g` to get community object `cd` and then use `plot(cd,g)` to make a graph where the communities are contained in translucent blobs. However, I also want to colour the vertices, and it seems as if `plot` overrides the vertex colouring I give to `V(g)$names`.

Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
v1 <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9)
v2 <- c(2,3,3,4,5,6,5,8,9,7)

graph <- data.frame(v1,v2)
g <- graph.data.frame(graph, directed=FALSE)

cd <- fastgreedy.community(g)

vcolor <- c("white", "white", "white",
             "blue", "blue", "blue",
             "red", "red", "red")

vertex_attr(g)$color <- vcolor

plot(g)
plot(cd,g)
```

When you `plot(g)`, the vertices are red, white and blue. However, when you `plot(cd,g)` they are blue, green and orange.

`plot(g)`:

[image: plot(g)]

`plot(cd,g)`:

[image: plot(cd,g)]

I want to keep the translucent blobs, but force my own coloring. The reason is I want to compare community membership (blobs) to another classification (vertex colors).

I did not have the same problem when I changed vertex labels. Also I should note that this did not work:

```
plot(cd,g,vertex.color=vcolor)
```

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate this is an old question but I have been struggling with it also and think I have found a simple answer, in case its helpful. Using you example:

```
v1 <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9)
v2 <- c(2,3,3,4,5,6,5,8,9,7)

graph <- data.frame(v1,v2)
g <- graph.data.frame(graph, directed=FALSE)

cd <- fastgreedy.community(g)

vcolor <- c("white", "white", "white",
            "blue", "blue", "blue",
            "red", "red", "red")

plot(cd,g,
     col = vcolor)
```

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU!